# What is the effect of mapping with a newtype constructor

Tags: haskell, newtype

In Chapter 8 of [thinking with types](https://leanpub.com/thinking-with-types) I learned that the `fmap Sum` part of

```hs
fastSum :: [Int] -> Int
fastSum = getSum . mconcat . fmap Sum
```

has a `O(n)` runtime cost, whereas using `coerce` instead avoids that overhead.

I know `newtype`s have no representation overhead, but what I do not understand is what is the runtime effect of mapping a newtype constructor over a list. I thought this would only have a compile-time overhead, and it should be just `O(1)`, since the compiler only needs to know the type of the `fmap SomeNewtypeCtr` expression.

Comment: When you write fmap at list types, you are saying you want to traverse the list. Unless there is a rewrite rule in scope that replaces that code with something else, you should expect that it will (if the result is demanded) actually traverse the list.

Comment: Hmmm, and what happens in this traversal at runtime level? Just an `fmap` with a no-op? (i.e. the list is just traversed)

Comment: The same as `fmap id`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to understand what Haskell exactly does in such cases, because of optimization. Haskell only mandates what is the result, not how it is obtained.

Some possibilities:

- `fmap Sum` performs a list scan, and copies each cell and each element;
- `fmap Sum` performs a list scan, and copies each cell but not the elements (the new cells point to the old elements);
- `fmap Sum` does not scan the list at all and is automatically optimized to a no-op.

I tried [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) to inspect the generated Core and assembly. Note that it still uses an old GHC 8.6.2. Still, I turned optimization on (`-O2`) and compiled

```
foo :: [Int] -> [Sum Int]
foo = fmap Sum
```

and obtained

```
foo = Example.foo1 `cast` (.....)
Example.foo1 = \ (v_a1iF :: [Int]) -> v_a1iF
```

Hence `foo` becomes the identity function, suitably coerced, producing the assembly

```
   movq %r14,%rbx
   andq $-8,%rbx
   jmp *(%rbx)
```

which should be, roughly speaking, the equivalent of an immediate return in the GHC runtime system.

Concluding: `Data.Coerce.coerce` is very nice since it ensures a no-op, but even plain Haskell, after optimization, can be surprisingly efficient.

Comment: Somehow, I find the beginning part of this answer is misleading. It's true that "Haskell only mandates what is the result, not how it is obtained", but usually when talking about performance we *do* want to go into the implementation details of GHC, which does define what `fmap Sum` does. By rights: memory is (lazily) allocated for new list cells, and each cell (once made) contains a pointer to the old element. *However*, the standard library also has a `map coerce = coerce` `RULE` written down somewhere to change this to just a cast. Disabling it should return the behavior to what's "right".

Comment: @HTNW I can partially agree. On one hand, it's true that we need to dig inside GHC details to understand the performance implications. On the other side, we should not: relying on the optimizer to rewrite an O(N) algorithm into a O(1) one is risky, IMO, unless there is an explicit guarantee in some docs. Future GHC might use a different optimizer which might be generally better but fail to optimize our specific case. Currently, `coerce` is guaranteed O(1) by the docs, `fmap Sum` is not, even the current optimizer is smart enough to make it O(1).

Comment: ? I'm fairly sure `fmap Sum` *is* guaranteed to optimize to `coerce` (as in, it's somewhere in the documentation that it should work this way and if it stops working that way it is a GHC bug, and you shouldn't just throw up your hands and say "optimization finicky" and give up.)

Comment: @HTNW If it is guaranteed to optimize, then I agree with your point.

Comment: I believe the rules are: a `RULE` is imported and exported like an `instance`. Assuming a given `RULE` is visible and enabled when a file is compiled (`-O2` enables all `RULE`s, I think there's an option for just toggling all `RULE`s apart from other optimizations, and I think there's a fine grained option for toggling rules by name), the `RULE` is guaranteed to be applied to every location where the LHS matches. It's not really the optimizer that's doing this. It's a human-written command to the compiler, which makes it less finicky.

Comment: @HTNW there is a `RULE` which is effectively `map coerce = coerce` but I couldn't find one for `fmap`

Comment: There isn't. However, I think []'s fmap is INLINE and defined as map. The order of rewrites is (and this is guaranteed) fmap coerce -> map coerce -> coerce